# tvOS performsegue in a nested TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, tvos

I have been having issues calling the performsegue method on my custom CollectionViewCell. My view hierarchy is UIView-UITableView-UICollectionView. The tableview is a static tableview with a collectionview inside my "CustomTableViewCell". Because I am using tvOS I read I should be using a UITapGestureRecognizer instead of the collectionview(didSelectCell) function. Here is my method "tapped" which I know is hooked up properly because my print function works, the issue is I am getting an error "Value of type CustomTableViewCell has no member "perfromSegue" when I add the "self.performsegue" line. I tried to control+drag a segue from the cell to my next view but still nothing. I assume it has to do with the the type of class my "CustomTableViewCell" is but I am not sure what else to add to it.

cell for item which adds the gesture:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCollectionViewCell

    if cell.gestureRecognizers?.count == nil {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomTableViewCell.tapped(_:)))
        tap.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.select.rawValue)]
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

here is the tapped method:

```
func tapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let cell = gesture.view as? PostCollectionViewCell {
        //load next view pass movie
        guard let post = cell.post else {return;}
        print("\(post.title) tapped")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPost", sender: post)
    }
}
```

I've tried to replace the self.performsegue with cell.perfomsegue because technically that is where I get the information to pass in my "perfromSegue(identifier:) method. The last thing I was thinking is to somehow call the parent view of the CustomTableViewCell which would be the original ViewController but I cannot call the .performsegue on ViewController or ViewController.sharedController when I create a sharedController

Answer (score 0):

Add an extension to your uitableviewcell

```
extension UITableViewCell {
var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.nextResponder()
        if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
            return viewController
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

then in didSelectItemAtIndexPath

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if let viewController = parentViewController as? NameOfYourViewController {
        viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("seguename", sender: nil)
    }
}
```